# Why does font-icon render outside of its content area? and how to fix it?

Tags: css, webfonts, glyphicons, icon-fonts

I have a `.woff` font file consisting of `font-icons`. These icons are rendered differently in Mac and in Windows. I suspect the reason to be different Win Ascent/Descent and HHead Ascent/Descent values in font metrics.

This icon-font file is generated from `svg` files using [`webfonts-generator`](https://github.com/sunflowerdeath/webfonts-generator) package

Here is the snapshot of same icon rendered in both mac and windows

Mac:
[image]

Windows:
[image]

could anyone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] instead of screenshots.

Comment: We could be help you if you show us your html and css code. :)

Answer (score -1):

may be your line-height is less than font-size